# arm-none-eabi global object

Tags: c++, arm, ld

I'm trying to compile something like this with arm-none-eabi:

```
class test
{
  public:
    test(void);
    int do_something(void);
}

test t;

int main(void)
{
  t.do_something();
}
```

But I'm still getting error:
MAIN.CPP:29: undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Do You have any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your linker parameters? Are you using `-nostartfiles` flag or something?

Comment: I'm using only -Wl -nostartfiles
when I try test *t; t->do_something(); there is no problem with linking...

Comment: This is what I was asking about. And do you have your own start file?

Comment: Oh, thank You very much, I forgot to add provided board_setup.S to linking command :/